# Search with complete suggester and german analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I created a simple index with a suggest field and a completion type. I indexed some city names. For the suggest field I use a german analyzer.

```
PUT city_de
{
  "mappings": {
    "city" : {
      "properties": {
        "name" : {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "german"
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "german"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The analyzer works fine and the search by using umlauts is good. Also the autocompletion is perfect. But I faced an issue by searching for the term `wie`.

Lets say I have two documents `Wiesbaden` and `Wien` with the same name as suggest completion term.

If I searching for `wie` I assume that the cities `Wien` and `Wiesbaden` are in the response. But unfortunately I get no response. I suppose that `wie` has a restriction because of the german analyzer. Because if I search for `wi` or `wies` I get valid responses.

Same is for term `was`, `er`, `sie`, `und` which looks like stemming words in german.

Do I need any additional configuration to get also a result if I search for `wie` or `was`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

Searching city names by prefix

"wie" should find "Wien" or "Wiesbaden"

## Possible solution approach

For the usecase I would suggest using an `edge n-gram` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html and `ASCII folding` the terms https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html.

Example

```
wien
token   position    start offset    end offset
w   0   0   1
wi  1   0   2
wie 2   0   3
wien    3   0   4



wiesbaden
token   position    start offset    end offset
w   0   0   1
wi  1   0   2
wie 2   0   3
wies    3   0   4
...
wiesbaden   8   0   9
```

Keep in mind that the system has to work in a asymmetric way now. The query should not be analyzed (use keyword) but the data in the index has to be analyzed.

There are two ways to achieve this:
1.) Add the query analyzer to use the query
2.) Bind the query analyzer to the field

```
"cities": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer", <-- index time analyzer
            "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search" <-- search time analyzer
          }
        }
      }
```

## Why does the german analyzer not work

The analyzer is designed for german text and uses an easy algorithm to remove flection and morphology.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#german-analyzer
Here is an example for the typical terms generated by this tokenizer

```
Hallo hier ist der Text über Wiesbaden und Wien. Es scheint angebracht über Wände und Wandern zu sprechen. 

hallo   0   0   5
text    4   19  23
wiesbad 6   29  38
wien    8   43  47
scheint 10  52  59
angebracht  11  60  70
wand    13  76  81
wandern 15  86  93
sprech
```

If it works on city names this happens just by coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will get through the docs you provided. What I was reading is that if the search_analyzer is not configured it will be the same as the analyzer. So I reindexed my cities by using german analyzer and stander search_analyzer. Is it still working by coincidence?

Comment: Yes the problem is that you want to analyze the data indexed but not the query. So you would need a separated analyzer for that. I will extend the answer and put a config example in there,

Comment: You can check the analyzers at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html . I would refrain from using german_analyzer for anything but text that contains standard nouns and verbs and never use it for named entities.

Comment: I see the benefits of an edge n-gram analyse. But how do I get the search working for example `münchen`. `munchen` and `muenchen` should also work?

Comment: for `munchen`ascii-flatten/ascii-folding is a possible solution (see link in 
 answer). It removes all diacritics. For the `Umschrift` ä -> ae and so on you need to define these by hand.